# AC Black Flag: how to show all items with overlay?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Is there any way to show all map items inside the visual with overlays? I was once able to do it but I don't rember anymore the hotkey I used for PC.

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something? This is a screenshot of AC Unity, but the question is about Black Flag.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can see the map nodes in their respective locations in game is when you are standing on a viewpoint. There is no hotkey which will allow you to get this same functionality when you are playing normally.

Comment: on a viewpoint how to show all of them ?

Comment: It will only show what you have discovered before either on your adventures or through the viewpoints.